# How does the splitting in this molecule take place?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

> Consider the following molecule and data:
>
> [image: alkane]
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \mathrm{H_a} &= \pu{1.0 ppm} &\quad J_\mathrm{ab} &= \pu{5.0 Hz}\\
> \mathrm{H_b} &= \pu{3.0 ppm} &\quad J_\mathrm{bc} &= \pu{8.0 Hz}\\
> \mathrm{H_c} &= \pu{6.0 ppm} &\quad J_\mathrm{ac} &= \pu{1.0 Hz}\\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Draw a splitting diagram for $\mathrm{H_b}.$ $(\pu{1 box} = \pu{1 Hz})$

Tried to draw the splitting diagram and ended up with this diagram:

[image: My splitting diagram]

I am also stuck as to how to draw the spectrum of the whole molecule as I feel $\mathrm{H_a}$ would be triplet of triplet. Am I on the right track and how to draw the sketch of the spectrum?

Comment: You missed a split. The central peak must also split on the last coupling.

Answer (score 3):

According to given data, you may consider expected peak patterns are not complicated such as $\mathrm{ABX}$ or $\mathrm{A_2B}$  patterns (more reading [look here](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/notes-5-hmr-12-ABX.pdf). This is simply a  $\mathrm{A_2X}$  pattern ($\delta_X = \pu{6 ppm}$ and $\delta_A = \pu{1 ppm}$ without geminal coupling of two $\ce{H_b}$ protons), and hence, peak is a $dt$ for $\ce{H_b}$ as depicted below with relative heights of the peaks:

[image: Hb peak]

Similarly, $\ce{H_c}$ is also a $dt$ resonance with $J = 1 \text{ & } \pu{8 Hz}$ and $\ce{H_a}$ is a $tt$ with $J = 1 \text{ & } \pu{5 Hz}$. OP should able to figure out the intensities of relevant peaks.

**A valuable reference:**

Roy H. Bible, Jr., Ph.D., In *Interpretation of NMR Spectra: An Empirical Approach*; Springer Science: New York, NY, 1965 (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-8288-1) (Note: Most relavent to this question is chapter 4 of the book titled "Higher-Order Spin Patterns and Multiple Resonance").